# Constructor injection - binding two separate configuration dependencies into a repository class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

What is the best practice, following DI, to create two separate repository classes...e.g.

```
public class FirstDbRepo : Repository

public class SecondDbRepo : Repository
```

That essentially implement the Repository class shown below

```
namespace MyApp.Persistence
{
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : EntityBase
    {
        public IConfig Config { get; set; }
        private Database Database 
        { 
            get 
            {
                 // Use Config to get connection
            }; 
            set; 
        }

        public Repository(IConfig config)
        {
            Config = config;
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            // Use database to get items
        }

        public T CreateItem(T item)
        {
            // Use database to create item
        }
    }
}
```

But to inject different config values/instances...

```
public interface IConfig
{
    string DatabaseName{ get; }
    string DatabaseEndpoint{ get; }
    string DatabaseAuthKey{ get; }
}
```

The first thing I thought of was to create marker interfaces, but wanted to know if this smells...is there a more correct way to do this using DI?

```
public interface IFirstDbRepo { }

public class FirstDbRepo<T> : Repository<T> where T: EntityBase
{
    public FirstDbRepo(FirstConfig config)
        : base(config)
    { }
}

public class FirstConfig : IConfig
{
    public string DatabaseName{ get { return "MyName" }; } // From web.config
}
```

And then use a ninject binding for each repo...the consumer could use as follows

```
public class Consumer() {
     private readonly IFirstDbRepo _firstRepo;
     public Consumer(IFirstDbRepo firstRepo) {
         _firstRepo = firstRepo;
     }
}
```

Comment: Your `Consumer` class has a dependency on the concrete class `FirstDbRepo` though? Ideally your `T` would be disjoint between the two, then you could just split which implementation you get based on the type of `T`, otherwise I would roll a Factory pattern here instead, but there may be a better way than that :P

Comment: Using marker interfaces is fine as well if you don't want to sue contextual binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bind<IConfig>().To<MyConfigOne>().WhenInjectedInto(typeof(FirstDbRepo));
Bind<IConfig>().To<MyConfigTwo>().WhenInjectedInto(typeof(SecondDbRepo ));
```

[Contextual binding](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding)